# Linux modprob cannot load Nvidia driver

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, nvidia-graphics-card, kali-linux

I’m trying to install nvidia driver for my Kali Linux machine, it was running well with the default nouveau driver.

I followed this tutorial https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux/

After the installation, display resolution become very low. So I checked device status with
`lspci -s 26:00.0 –v` And the output is like this

```
26:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 Rev. A] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Device 7377:1501
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10, IOMMU group 15
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidia
```

Kernel modules does show Nvidia, but the `kernel driver in use` is not shown.

I noticed that during boot up, there is an error of
`System[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules` So I checked with `systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service` command.
The output shows nvidia-current and nvidia-current-modeset could not be found as following

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-06-02 00:54:24 HKT; 7h left
       Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
             man:modules-load.d(5)
    Process: 446 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 446 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 10ms

Jun 02 00:54:24 kali systemd-modules-load[455]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia-current not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-kali3-amd64
Jun 02 00:54:24 kali systemd-modules-load[453]: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:990 command_do() Error running install command 'modprobe -i nvidia-current ' for module nvidia: retcode 1
Jun 02 00:54:24 kali systemd-modules-load[453]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Invalid argument
Jun 02 00:54:24 kali systemd-modules-load[459]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia-current-modeset not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-kali3-amd64
Jun 02 00:54:24 kali systemd-modules-load[451]: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:990 command_do() Error running install command 'modprobe nvidia ; modprobe -i nvidia-current-modeset ' for module nvidia_modeset: retcode 1
Jun 02 00:54:24 kali systemd-modules-load[451]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_modeset': Invalid argument
Jun 02 00:54:24 kali systemd-modules-load[464]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia-current-drm not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-kali3-amd64
Notice: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.
```

Here is the Nvidia related files under /lib/modules

```
./modules/5.15.0-kali3-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/typec/altmodes/typec_nvidia.ko
./modules/5.15.0-kali3-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/nvidia/forcedeth.ko
```

Besides purge all nvidia packages and re-install, I tried to add nouveau to the `nvidia-blacklists-nouveau.conf`, still the same result.
I remember that I have successfully installed this driver once before (about 1-1.5 years ago), I am not sure what went wrong here, any advice is welcomed. Thanks.

GPU: RTX2060
CPU: R5-2600

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks, tried, but still the same

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, were you able to solve yours?

Comment: @aldr nope, can't fix it, I ended up to switch os to ubuntu, worked perfectly. kali is just not supporting these well i guess.